# caret: Choosing the correct number of cores in parallel backend

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am trying to use `caret` to cross-validate an elastic net model using the `glmnet` implementation on an Ubuntu machine with 8 CPU cores & 32 GB of RAM. When I train sequentially, I am maxing out CPU usage on one core, but using 50% of the memory on average.

- When I use `doMC(cores = xxx)`, do I need to worry about only registering xxx  = floor(100/y) cores, where y is the memory usage of the model when using a single core (in %), in order to not run out of memory?
- Does `caret` have any heuristics that allow it to figure out the max. number of cores to use?
- Is there any set of heuristics that I can use to dynamically adjust the number of cores to use my computing resources optimally across different sizes of data and model complexities?

---

## Edit:

FWIW, attempting to use 8 cores made my machine unresponsive. Clearly `caret` does not check to see if the spawning `xxx` processes is likely to be problematic. How can I then choose the number of cores dynamically?

Comment: `library(parallel)

detectCores()`

This is a way to determine how many cores are available. The handling of the return value is OS dependent, but it would be interesting to know how many R thinks is available to it in your setup.  May return a number smaller than 8.

Comment: @Mike That is not the point. I know that there are 8 cores, but assume that there are fewer. I will run out of memory, _in this case_ much before 4, or 6 or 8 cores are used. What I need is a heuristic and efficient way to figure out how many cores to register for the _problem at hand_.

Answer (score 3):

> Clearly caret does not check to see if the spawning xxx processes is likely to be problematic.

True; it cannot predict future performance of your computer.

You should get an understanding of how much memory you use for modeling use when running sequentially. You can start the training and use `top` or other methods to estimate the amount of ram used then kill the process. If sequentially you use *X* GB of RAM  sequentially, running on *M* cores will require *X(M+1)* GB of ram.

Comment: Thanks topepo. This is what I have been doing.